# SessionLoginSample return empty graph data file in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm using facebook example SessionLoginSample.
I have added to the file LoginUsingActivityActivity.java couple of things:
1. the facebook login button(com.facebook.widget.LoginButton)
2. read premissions(in the onCreate:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"email"}));
```

)
this the approve screen I really see I'm asking to read the mail.
but in the link:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=CAAFaKtb7Pg4BAK9q1vPnZAXZBnYO3fWlTVnFQmuqZAoqvwMzNibnH7TLtszjsG7ZBxbntmpMLPvTKpucUoMb9ej2ieJBQ0E9Au2anZAkCzMkjBfU234ioQdL2mgO9aBGveMGFrv2ZCvpajDd3m5cGv6x6h7iZABnP5xYOsuUe4XcZByZAYxdARuwUxWxZBhno4IxTzVeJveI9caNkIxs41F9Kl
I getn an empty file:

```
{
"data": [  
]
}
```

I checked it with the [debug tool(the link include the key)](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken?q=CAAFaKtb7Pg4BAK9q1vPnZAXZBnYO3fWlTVnFQmuqZAoqvwMzNibnH7TLtszjsG7ZBxbntmpMLPvTKpucUoMb9ej2ieJBQ0E9Au2anZAkCzMkjBfU234ioQdL2mgO9aBGveMGFrv2ZCvpajDd3m5cGv6x6h7iZABnP5xYOsuUe4XcZByZAYxdARuwUxWxZBhno4IxTzVeJveI9caNkIxs41F9Kl&version=v2.0), but everything look ok
Maybe do you have an idea?

I Found the solution:
The problem it with the link from the sample app.
The current link is https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAAFaKtb7Pg4BAK9q1vPnZAXZBnYO3fWlTVnFQmuqZAoqvwMzNibnH7TLtszjsG7ZBxbntmpMLPvTKpucUoMb9ej2ieJBQ0E9Au2anZAkCzMkjBfU234ioQdL2mgO9aBGveMGFrv2ZCvpajDd3m5cGv6x6h7iZABnP5xYOsuUe4XcZByZAYxdARuwUxWxZBhno4IxTzVeJveI9caNkIxs41F9Kl.
I have removed the word "friends" and now is show only "me"

Thank you

Comment: are you sure that the token is correct? Maybe you put the application token and not the user access token? Does this work https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends&version=v2.0

Comment: Thank you, this is working with the same token.But, I looks like I get by default the "me/friends" and not "me/". how do I read it from the response? the general data. Thank you

Comment: Found the problem, thank you!! The example ask only for the friends!!

Answer (score 0):

try adding the permission "`basic_info`"

like this:

```
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"email","basic_info"}));
```